# Is it possible to remove error messages from bash

Tags: bash

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the error messages from bash. So for example, a bash script take a users input and if it runs properly in the terminal it doesn't return anything (it just runs the command), but if it fails, then it removes the error message and runs another script. Initially I thought this would be possible using \e[K, but that won't work I don't think. || doesn't work either as it still returns the error message before running the secondary command. Is there any way I can do this.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

```
bash script1 2>/dev/null || bash script2
```

This would redirect `STDERR` of script1 to `/dev/null` and execute `script2` if the former exited with a non-zero status code.

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks. I will use that. But is it possible to use an ASCII escape code of some form? Just wondering.

Comment: @bd3dowling I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  Note that the _error_ messages from the script would be written to `STDERR` and you'd either need to redirect those to `/dev/null` to get rid of those, or have those redirected to `STDOUT` and manipulate it.

Comment: I see, ok. I get it now.

Comment: ANSI escape codes could only be used to affect how the error messages are displayed on the terminal, specifically by erasing them after the fact. Redirecting them to `/dev/null` prevents them from ever being displayed in the first case, a much cleaner solution.